# "There are no registered paths for namespace "App"." FosRestBundle, Symfony, POST/DELETE

Tags: api, symfony, twig, fosrestbundle

I receive such a message "There are no registered paths for namespace "App"" while doing post or delete requests to my API. GET works. I use FosUserBundle.

*config.yml*

```
...
fos_rest:
    body_converter:
      enabled: true
      validate: true
      validation_errors_argument: validationErrors
    exception:
      enabled: true
      exception_controller: 'AppBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    routing_loader:
          default_format: json
          include_format: false
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
...
```

*PersonRestController.php*

```
...
class PersonRestController extends AbstractController {

    use ControllerTrait;

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function getPersonsAction() {
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Person::class)
            ->findAll();
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View(statusCode=201)
     * @ParamConverter("person", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     * @Rest\NoRoute()
     */
    public function postPersonsAction(Person $person, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors) {
        if (count($validationErrors) > 0) {
            throw new ValidationException($validationErrors);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();

        return $person;
    }

    /**
    * @Rest\View()
    */
    public function deletePersonsAction(?Person $person) {

        if($person === null) {
            return $this->view(null, 404);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($person);
        $em->flush();

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function getPersonAction(?Person $person) {
        if($person === null) {
            return $this->view(null, 404);
        }

        return $person;
    }
}
...
```

Error:

[image: error]

I've checked my config.yml. It shows no duplicate.
The POST method still works despite the error, DELETE doesn't however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you used `App\` instead of `AppBundle\` in a `use` statement (check also your configuration files).

Make sure that you have include the following lines in *config.yml* :

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
```

You should also extend `FOSRestController` instead of using the Trait ([FOSRestBundle   Step 2: The view layer](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html))

**NB** : I'm assuming that you use `AppBundle` as the main bundle because your using it in *config.xml* for key `exception_controller`.